# UIButton titleLabel not sensible or touchable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitouch

I'm developing an app ios (base 7.0) that was previously initiated by another developer. I'm in an absurd condition. All UIButton have titleLabel not touch sensitive. The button executes the method only if the tap on button but out of the label (or titleLabel). I tried to import the controller with.h .m and .xib file into another project and the buttons work. There must be some setting globally changing the behavior of UIButton .. you have any ideas ??

Comment: is "`userInteractionEnabled`" set to false?  and to be touch sensitive, the labels need gesture recognizers attached...  better to change the label into a UIButton.

Comment: Hi, userInteractionEnabled is set to ON and there isn't any UILabel, only UIButton. The tile of button is not sensitive, the area around the title is sensitive

Comment: You need to show some code as to how the buttons are being created/setup - the behaviour you defined is not normal, so the program must be doing something to change the behaviour

Comment: Also, check for any UIButton categories and for attributed titles, and for UILabel categories. But as Paulw11, we can't really help you with the information provided.

Comment: Hi, i solved removin an UILabel category... thanks!